# How do I pass a default method as a parameter in Python

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
class class1():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def method1(self):
        pass

def independent_method(class1_instance, param2='method1'):
    return class1_instance.param2()

c = class1()
independent_method(c)
```

I get this error:

```
'class1' object has no attribute 'param2'
```

How do I get around this problem? I've tried different variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`__getattribute__`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dunderattr/getattribute.html) to fetch the method by its given name in param2:

```py
class class1():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def method1(self):
        pass

def independent_method(class1_instance, param2='method1'):
    return class1_instance.__getattribute__(param2)()

c = class1()
independent_method(c)
```

You can also use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)... that's actually a better way to do so.

```py
class class1():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def method1(self):
        pass

def independent_method(class1_instance, param2='method1'):
    return getattr(class1_instance, param2)()

c = class1()
independent_method(c)
```